# Is there a way to know what is the url before it will be encoded?

Tags: web, url, special-characters, urlencode, space

I want to know if there is a way to know the inputted URL before encoding.

My problem is once I enter the URL, space automatically encodes to %20. For example, I have a URL that has this parameter ?a=on e

I need to get this string "a=on e" because I need to differentiate whether the user input is a space or %20.

Comment: Adding a snippet of your code would go a long way in helping the helpers help you. Please do so.

Answer (score 0):

`on%20e` is data you got from `uri` encode. So if you want to get correct data from `url`, you mus decode query param.

**For ex:**

```
String encodeResult = URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");    System.out.println(encodeResult); // result is on%20e
String decodeResult =    URLDecoder.decode(encodeResult); System.out.println(decodeResult); // result is on e
```

You only need to keep in mind to encode only the individual query string parameter name and/or value, not the entire `URL`